# Trying to achieve this animation effect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve an effect like the one on this page (click the submit button).

http://www.thewildtimes.com

The modal drops down from the top of the page. I think it's a jQuery easing effect, but I am a little baffled by all the options.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easing they're using is called `easeOutBack`, it really just boils down to this:

```
.animate({
   left  : ( ($(document).width() - this.options.BoxStyles.width) / 2),
   top   : ( $(document).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() - this.Box.outerHeight()) / 2 )
 }, {
    duration  : this.options.moveDuration,
    easing    : 'easeOutBack'
 });
```

[Here's their effect packed up in a stand-alone demo to show it a bit better](http://jsfiddle.net/PeUsZ/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure its one of these easing functions http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/